# Latest part of a psql SPLIT

Tags: postgresql, split

PSQL Split is a function that gets the n part from a splitted string:

https://www.educba.com/postgresql-split_part/

So, if we have:

```
SELECT SPLIT_PART('X,Y,Z', ',', 1);
```

We will get X.

My database has a column with values like:   `'X,Y'`, `'X,Y,Z,W'`, etc

I need to retrieve the latest part of the split-ed string. I mean

For  `'X,Y'`   -->  `'Y'`
For  `'X,Y,Z,W'` --> `'W'`

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can split it into an array and then pick the last element:

```
select (string_to_array(the_column, ','))[cardinality(string_to_array(the_column, ','))]
from the_table
```